# Impala ODBC Driver for Multiple Insert

Tags: odbc, driver, impala

I have a problem with multiple inserts via odbc Impala (last version).

I am trying to insert two thousand rows in a Impala table (on Cloudera) with 4 columns but I receive two errors :

> [Cloudera][SQLEngine] (31580) The length of the statement exceeds the maximum: 16384.
>   [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: ...

I'm using query parameterized query :

```
INSERT INTO name_table (a,b,c,d) VALUES (?,?,?,?) , (?,?,?,?) , ....
```

Now my question is :

Is there a way to insert millions of rows using the odbc driver without using single inserts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there's a maximum of 16384 characters for a query, which should be what looks like a much higher limit. We're currently investigating to see if there's a reason for this low limit.

That said, a more efficient way of inserting multiple values via ODBC would be to use the query:

`INSERT INTO name_table (a,b,c,d) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`

and then use array binding to bind multiple parameter sets to your parameters. In this way, the driver can optimize the execution internally and you don't run into a query length limitation. Have you tried this already?

Comment: Just an aside, an upcoming release of the driver will increase the limit to the practical limits supported by Impala.

Comment: Could you provide and example how multiple rows can be inserted in a single INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

I had already tried to execute the following code:

```
        OdbcCommand oComm = oConn.CreateCommand();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        sb.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO {0}.{1} (a,b,c,d) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", dbName, tableName);



        List<OdbcParameter> psl = new List<OdbcParameter>(1000 * 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {

            var odbcParameter = new OdbcParameter();
            odbcParameter.ParameterName = "@a";
            odbcParameter.OdbcType = OdbcType.Text;
            odbcParameter.Value ="a"+i;
            psl.Add(odbcParameter);

            odbcParameter = new OdbcParameter();
            odbcParameter.ParameterName = "@b";
            odbcParameter.OdbcType = OdbcType.Text;
            odbcParameter.Value = "b" + i;
            psl.Add(odbcParameter);

            odbcParameter = new OdbcParameter();
            odbcParameter.ParameterName = "@c";
            odbcParameter.OdbcType = OdbcType.Text;
            odbcParameter.Value = "c" + i;
            psl.Add(odbcParameter);

            odbcParameter = new OdbcParameter();
            odbcParameter.ParameterName = "@d";
            odbcParameter.Value = "d" + i;
            odbcParameter.OdbcType = OdbcType.Text;
            psl.Add(odbcParameter);


        }


        oComm.Parameters.AddRange(psl.ToArray());

        oComm.CommandText = sb.ToString();

        oComm.executeNonQUery();
```

At the end, my table is composed from only one record with the first four parameter's values.

There is something wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: You're unfortunately using the ADO.NET Provider for ODBC (a C# wrapper over ODBC) which limits how you can interact with the ODBC API. As written, you're simply adding a bunch of values to a list and then setting the range to that entire set for your 4 parameters, not using multiple sets of 4. Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx instead?

Comment: I've tried to use OdbcDataAdapter but the odbc executes one insert statement for each new row in my DataTable with bad performance.
Some advice or example for my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately if the ADO.NET Provider for ODBC is transforming this into a sub-optimal execution at the ODBC layer, you're out of luck. The limit of 16384 characters has been removed and will go out in the next release of the driver, however I'm not sure when that will eventually become public for you. I would bug Cloudera about this.

Comment: Could you solve this problem since then? Any chance you can update your question with the solution?